# Available time slot in a table reservation system SQL queries

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to make a simple reservation system. It has only two tables

1. **Facility**, where the basic information about the facility is stored (facility could be a table in the restaurant)

   ```
    id  name    open_from  open_to
    1   Table1  08:00      17:00
    2   Table2  08:00      17:00
    3   Table3  08:00      17:00
    4   Table4  08:00      17:00
   ```

The limitations of the facility are the opening hours (open_from, open_to)

2. **Reservation**, where the information about the reservation is stored

   ```
   id   facility_id   date         timefrom   duration
   1    1             2024-01-05   09:00      90
   2    2             2024-01-05   09:00      90
   3    3             2024-01-05   09:00      90
   4    4             2024-01-05   09:00      90
   5    1             2024-01-05   14:00      60
   6    2             2024-01-05   14:00      60
   7    3             2024-01-05   14:00      60
   8    4             2024-01-05   14:00      60
   ```

The data in this table shows the information about the reservation - which facility is reserved, at what date and time and how long the reservation will last (in minutes). The above example displays, that all four tables are booked at 09:00 for 90 minutes and at 14:00 for 60 minutes.

Now I'm looking for two SQL outputs.

1. **Finding available slots**. The input is the date and duration (duration can be 60, 90 or 120 mins). The output should be the available time slots, always starting at the hour and 30 mins after the hour (i.e. 08:00, 08:30, 09:00...) between the opening hours of the facility.
2. **Finding available facilities**. Based on the output from query #1 (time slot with the specific duration on a specific date), the output of the second query should be all available facilities during this slot (either none, some of them, or all).

I created DB fiddle with above mentioned data https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kecFiRLNVqrjJHZPwwjmQE/0

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you, David

Comment: what does a facility that's open past midnight or open all day look like?

Comment: is this really mysql 5.7 (which your fiddle uses)?  that's past end of life, no longer receiving security updates; it should be considered a security risk

Comment: what timezone are these times in (only relevant if your from/to can include a dst transition)?

Comment: note that mysql does not support DDL (create table, alter table) as part of a transaction; when you do one of these, it immediately commits any underway transaction and ends it.

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my approach:**

- Created a `RECURSIVE CTE` to generate timeslots based on the `open_from` and `open_to` columns in 30 minute intervals.
- Added the `duration` column to the `timefrom` column to get the window of time for the reservation. (IE: reservation is at 9:00 and ends at 10:30.)
- `LEFT JOIN` the `reservations` table to `cte_timeslots`
  where the applicable `facility_id` has a reservation within a timeslot.
- Apply `WHERE` predicate to filter out facilities/timeslots with a reservation.

**Important Notes:**

- I'd recommend commenting out the "WHERE b.id is NULL" and review the output to understand the query better.
- Works on MySQLversion 8.0. I couldn't CTEs with v5.7.
- You probably want to set a cut-off time for the last reservation. Currently, you can schedule a reservation at closing time and that may not be ideal.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `facility` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `open_from` time NOT NULL,
  `open_to` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `facility` (`id`, `name`, `open_from`, `open_to`) VALUES
(1, 'Table 1', '08:00:00', '17:00:00'),
(2, 'Table 2', '08:00:00', '17:00:00'),
(3, 'Table 3', '08:00:00', '17:00:00'),
(4, 'Table 4', '08:00:00', '16:00:00');

CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `facility_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `timefrom` time NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `reservation` (`id`, `facility_id`, `date`, `timefrom`, `duration`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2024-01-05', '09:00:00', 90),
(2, 2, '2024-01-05', '09:00:00', 90),
(3, 3, '2024-01-05', '09:00:00', 90),
(4, 4, '2024-01-05', '09:00:00', 90),
(5, 1, '2024-01-05', '14:00:00', 60),
(6, 2, '2024-01-05', '14:00:00', 60),
(7, 3, '2024-01-05', '14:00:00', 60),
(8, 4, '2024-01-05', '14:00:00', 60);


ALTER TABLE `facility`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `reservation`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `facility`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

ALTER TABLE `reservation`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
COMMIT;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH recursive cte_timeslots AS (
  SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.NAME, 
    a.open_from AS open_time_slot, 
    a.open_to 
  FROM 
    facility a
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    b.id, 
    b.NAME, 
    addtime(b.open_time_slot, '0:30') open_time_slot, 
    b.open_to 
  FROM 
    cte_timeslots b 
  WHERE 
    b.open_time_slot < b.open_to
) 
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.NAME, 
  a.open_time_slot, 
  b.res_date, 
  b.res_time_from, 
  b.res_time_to 
FROM 
  cte_timeslots a 
  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      a.id, 
      a.facility_id, 
      a.date AS res_date, 
      a.timefrom AS res_time_from, 
      a.duration, 
      date_add(
        a.timefrom, interval duration minute
      ) AS res_time_to 
    FROM 
      reservation a
  ) b ON a.id = b.facility_id 
  AND a.open_time_slot >= b.res_time_from 
  AND a.open_time_slot < b.res_time_to 
 WHERE b.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
  a.id, 
  a.NAME, 
  a.open_time_slot;
```

| id | NAME | open_time_slot | res_date | res_time_from | res_time_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Table 1 | 08:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 08:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 10:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 11:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 11:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 12:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 12:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 13:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 13:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 15:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 15:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 16:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 16:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Table 1 | 17:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 08:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 08:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 10:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 11:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 11:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 12:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 12:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 13:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 13:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 15:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 15:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 16:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 16:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Table 2 | 17:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 08:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 08:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 10:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 11:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 11:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 12:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 12:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 13:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 13:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 15:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 15:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 16:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 16:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Table 3 | 17:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 08:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 08:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 10:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 11:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 11:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 12:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 12:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 13:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 13:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 15:00:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 15:30:00 |  |  |  |
| 4 | Table 4 | 16:00:00 |  |  |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kecFiRLNVqrjJHZPwwjmQE/0)